# Azure facebook login on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, azure, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services

For my cordova application i am running a Azure .net backend.
To access it from the client i use the mobile service client plugin for cordova.

Now to my problem:
I want to allow a facebook login which is already supported by the mobile service client. Therefore i registered a FB-application as described in the azure [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-facebook-authentication/)

Everything works well when i access the published backend. However if i am running it locally, the facebook login fails without any helpful error message.
It must be a problem with the facebook app settings.

For the case where i am running on localhost, i created a second testapplication with the following settings:

[image]

[image]

For the valid oAuth redirect URIs i have tried different things.
Does anyone have an idea how i could solve this?fa

Comment: Are you using a client flow or a server flow?

Comment: Client...
All i do is to use the built in login with the facebook authentication provider:

           `mobileServiceClient.login("facebook").then(function () {
                successCB(connectusClient.currentUser);
            }, function (error) {
                errorCB(error);
                console.error("Facebooklogin failed")
            });`

Comment: As i said, when it is deployed everything works fine.
I am not able to get any meaningful error out of the mobileserviceclient.
Right now i think it could be because the login call uses https not http.

Comment: The way you are calling .login is server flow. If you want to use client flow facebook auth. it should be .login("facebook",[facebooktoken])
Which [facebooktoken] is the auth token you got back from facebook javascript SDK.

 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/

Comment: Thanks for that information, still i want to use the server side login flow :/

Comment: Did you already manage to do the fb-login when running the azure service locally in iis?

Comment: With Client flow, yes. I haven't tried server flow.